# Apsose.zip Entries doesn't contain folders when zip created by builtin win 11 zipper

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, zip, aspose

I am working on an online filemanager project. I recently added function where you can go inside a zip file and see the files and folders there. I used Aspose.zip library. In the controller i create the Archive from a stream.

```
return View(new Archive(stream));
```

Then in the view I display it using an Archive model.

```
@model Archive;
@foreach (var item in Model.Entries
{
  <span>@item.Name</span>
}
```

**If i create the zip file with the builtin windows zipper, the Archive.Entries doesn't contain any folders.** 
 But if i use winrar everythings working prefectly fine. 
 **How can you detect that it was made by the builtin zipper?**

Comment: Why do you care how the ZIP file was created? If the ZIP file contains directories then display them if not just show the files. And if you think the shown data are incorrect file a bug on the used library.

Comment: You can seek for Path.DirectorySeparatorChar or Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar withing the [Name](https://reference.aspose.com/zip/net/aspose.zip/archiveentry/name/) of an archive entry to find out directories inside the archive and detect  whether particular entry belong to the directory.